# start an activity through a voice trigger command

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have been searching from last 9 or 10 days but I didn't get lucky enough to get my hands on some understandable code. I want to start my main activity through a trigger word like "ok google" or "open" my application receives the command and then performs some action. How can this be don, please provide a sample code. 
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried. StackOverflow shouldn't be used to ask for code if none is given.

Comment: And try not to repost similar questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484309/an-application-that-is-able-to-perform-major-mobile-phone-tasks-through-voice

Comment: desperate times can make you do desperate things what would you do if somehow you don't know how code will be written but all you need is just a push. I wanted a push if I would have found even a little bit understandable and easily implementable I wouldn't have asked for "sample" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have a voice command that can open your when it's not open?

The only way you are allowed to do this is to use Accessibility Service. You will have to create your own service, implement the voice recognition, then user will have to manually turn the service on in their phone and based on the voice command, you can do whatever you want.

Basically:
Step 1) Develop [Accessibility service](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html)
Step 2) Merge speech recognition with the service.  [Here](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo) is an example of speech recognition.
Step 3) User MUST turn on accessibility service

You are basically trying to creating an App like [TalkBack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback&hl=en), but only for your own app, which is no easy task. But i'm sure you can figure it out

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.